# Gauss Seidel Convergence for symmetric negative definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Prove or disprove: "The Gauss-Seidel iteration is guaranteed to converge for a symmetric *negative* definite matrix".

It is well known enough that the GS iteration converges for symmetric positive definite matrices, see Golub and Van Loan, Theorem 10.1.2. (Theorem 11.2.3 p.615-616 on the 4th ed. 2013) However, when studying back tests for a qualifying exam, I came across this question and I can not find it proven or disproven anywhere.  The proof in Golub and Van Loan depends specifically on the fact that the matrix is positive definite.  My gut feeling is that symmetric negative definite isn't guaranteed to converge, but does anyone know otherwise?

---

Edit: My gut feeling appears to be wrong, at least based on a couple numerical experiments I ran.  So it seems like proving the statement is the way to go.  If anyone knows a proof, I'd be interested to see.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the (forward) Gauss-Seidel method for $Ax=b$, the approximate solution $x^{k+1}$ is computed from $x^k$ as 
$$
x^{k+1}_i
=
\frac{1}{a_{ii}}
\left[
b_i-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}a_{ij}x^{k+1}_j-\sum_{j=i+1}^na_{ij}x^k_j
\right].
$$
Since
$$
x^{k+1}_i
=
\frac{1}{(-a_{ii})}
\left[
(-b_i)-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}(-a_{ij})x^{k+1}_j-\sum_{j=i+1}^n(-a_{ij})x^k_j
\right],
$$
the iterates for solving $Ax=b$ and $(-A)x=(-b)$ are identical. So if the method converges for a positive definite matrix $A$, if also converges for a negative definite $A$.

In general, fixed point iterative methods induced by splittings $A=M-N$ and $(-A)=(-M)-(-N)$ ($M$ nonsingular) for solving $Ax=b$ and $-Ax=-b$, respectively, are equivalent (generate the same approximate solutions).